# Select 2 column and merge data

Tags: mysql, sql, flask, mariadb

I want to merge the same value in col1 and with there specific data in col2 and display it in html table. My sql table looks like this

```
+------+------+
|col1  |col2  |
+------+------+
|1     |test  |
+------+------+
|2     |test1 |
+------+------+
|1     |test2 |
+------+------+
|1     |test4 |
+------+------+
|2     |test8 |
+------+------+
```

The expected result is displayed in html table like this.

```
+------+------+
|      |test  |
|      |      |
|  1   |test1 |
|      |      |
|      |test2 |
+------+------+
|      |test4 |
|  2   |      |
|      |test8 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Handle these display related issues in your application code (eg: PHP, Java etc). MySQL is a RDBMS (that means tables). You cannot have one row in one column, and three rows in another. This is not Excel's `Merge Cells`.

Comment: Can you give examples how can i do it in PHP? other related question i found doesn't not fit to what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data is not explicit, but you might be looking for GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(col2 SEPARATOR '\n') col2
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY col1
```