# Select column and count the data

Tags: sql, flask, mariadb

Same as my last problem [Select 2 column and merge data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57883470/11576550)

Now i want to select and count ans_name and display them in the php as a Integer

```
table name = answer
+-------------+----------+
|que_name     |ans_name  |
+-------------+----------+
|true or false|true      |
+-------------+----------+
|true or false|true      |
+-------------+----------+
|true or false|false     |
+-------------+----------+
|true or false|true      |
+-------------+----------+
|true or false|false     |
+-------------+----------+
```

i tried to distinct first the ans_name to get the true and false then count them using where like this (obviously it doesn't work)
`select count(distinct ans_name) from answers`

The expected result is displayed in html table like this.

```
+------+----+
|true  |3   |
+------+----+
|false |2   |
+------+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need distinct count

```
select ans_name, count(*) from answers group by ans_name
```

Comment: sorry for late response. it works, but i modified it e.g. if it has another question i add where statement